# Why a resized desktop broswer and a mobile in terms of sizing are not the same when opening a web page? Example

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm looking for a theme to use on wordpress. Sometimes a page will load correctly on a resized web browser but not on mobile, even with the same dimensions it will load with some kind of bug (usually a misalignement). In this page for example ( http://demo.stylishthemes.co/mesh2-event ) the middle part moves to the right when on mobile. What causes problem like this? Isn't a mobile made to run as a "small desktop window"?

I tried edditing some parameters on Layer 3 div but no success.

```
<!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
´´´´
```

Comment: There are more subtleties at play when viewing a website through a mobile browser than just considering it a "small desktop window". Consider reading up on responsive css and virtual vs physical pixels. A good place to start is https://dev.opera.com/articles/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

esto va de acuerdo como esta estructurado en CSS, bien sabemos que una pagina web esta compuesto basicamente de HTML y CSS. un ejemplo

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    aside {
        flex-direction:column;
    }

    footer {
        justify-content:space-around;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your contribution. [This site requires content to be posted in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/5351721). Please revise the post to use English.

Comment: Hello Alxn, but on the example I gave, how would I know that a specific <div is flexible or not to run the paramenter?